# Calculating churn percentage in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a dataset with bank churn data and when trying to calculate overall churn % I'm getting 0

Here's my query input:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total_customers,
    SUM(CASE WHEN churn = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS churned_customers,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN churn = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS churn_rate_percentage
FROM
    bank_churn_data
```

As an output I get the amount of total customers, the amount of churned customers but the percentage comes out as 0.

Comment: Integer division at work. Try with 1.0 and 0.0 or  `COUNT(*)::numeric`. See [Math functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html): *numeric_type / numeric_type → numeric_type Division (for integral types, division truncates the result towards zero)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adrian commented, the issue is due to truncation when performing integer division. The following query explicitly casts the numerator in the division to `FLOAT` to avoid the truncation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total_customers,
    SUM(CASE WHEN churn = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS churned_customers,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN churn = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END::FLOAT) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS churn_rate_percentage
FROM
    bank_churn_data;
```

Replacing `SUM` with `COUNT` more directly expresses the intent and also runs slightly faster (~22% on my laptop):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total_customers,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE churn = 'Yes') AS churned_customers,
    (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE churn = 'Yes')::FLOAT / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS churn_rate_percentage
FROM
    bank_churn_data;
```

Both `SUM` and `COUNT` are acceptable: the performance difference is statistcally significant but doesn't make a big difference in real time. Even for 10M rows, the difference in real time on my laptop was only ~0.21 seconds (~0.97 seconds using `SUM` vs. ~0.76 seconds using `COUNT`).

Comment: This was super useful. Both of these queries worked, thank you!